# Reveal Tab with Unique content based on location

Tags: tabs, geolocation, location, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

Lots of marketing articles suggest using a coupon as an incentive in a reveal tab, but I don't see how you would prevent people who have liked your page from abusing the coupon by accessing it over and over.

In my app, I want to offer a coupon that the user sees only the first time they like a page. Users who have been to that page before would not be able to access it again.

I also want to limit who can see it based on location.

Answer (score 1):

When your iframe fan page is rendered, Facebook sents an HTTP POSt to your page with a signed_request post parameter.  If you [decode](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/) it, you will get details about whether they like your page and what country/language they are from.  If country works for you, then you are all set for that part.  Restricting the coupon to only being viewed is not possible based on the anonymous information Facebook sends.  You would need to create an application and have the user approve your application so you can get their ID and log that they have seen it.  This would also give you more detailed information about where they are located.

Comment: Thanks. What about the other part of my question? 

Say I didn't care about locations: How do you make the information in the reveal tab only seen once? 

It seems to me like the way it works now is that once someone likes a page, they can go back to the reveal tab and see the information under it anytime, which makes me wonder how people can use it for coupons or offers and not have the same people take advantage by using the coupon or offer over and over again.

Comment: You would need to make it as an application that people authenticate with so that you can get their Facebook user id.